# How to cleanup in pytest if setup_class failed?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest

My test setup:

```
class TestClass:
    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
       create_table(tb1)
       create_table(tb2)

    @classmethod
    def teardown_class(cls):
       drop_table(tb1)
       drop_table(tb2)   

    def setup_method(self, method):
        func()

    def teardown_method(self, method):
        func()

    def test_tc1(self):
        <tc_content>
        assert
```

Above module failed to create table tb2 in setup_class but successfully created table tb1. It exists with error but without executing teardown_class.
This creates error "table tb1 exists" while running the module next time.
Is there any way to drop tb1 before exiting from module even if tb2 creation failed.

Comment: Use `try: ... except` then, and if you are using a SQL database, a transaction you can roll back.

Comment: I'd also suggest to consider using fixtures instead.

Comment: @de1 can you please explain a little. I know what fixtures are but are you suggesting to change the structure altogether or enhancement

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate how you could refactor your code to use fixtures instead:

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(name='database_with_tables', scope='module')
def _database_with_tables():
    try:
        create_table(tb1)
        create_table(tb2)
        yield None # usually we would pass around a database connection / session
    finally:
        drop_table(tb1)
        drop_table(tb2)


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("database_with_tables")
class TestClass:
    def test_tc1(self):
        <tc_content>
        assert
```

You still need to handle exceptions thrown during table creation. In most cases, you would also want to pass around the database connection to the test method as well, in which case `pytest.mark.usefixtures` would no longer be necessary. The advantage of fixtures is that it declares what you need for the test, not how. The `scope` parameter could also be set to `session` to live longer.